# Word or a phrase for quick looking through a bookshelf

Tags: word-request

[image: Finding a book gif]

Would the act of quick looking through a shelf to find a book be called *"browsing through the shelf"*? Are there any alternatives to describe the same action?

Edit:

> "Which hex do I enter? Which wall do I look at? Which shelf do I ***skim through***? Which book do I open? What page do I read?"

What do you think, "skim through" works here?

Comment: *Browsing* has nothing to do with speed. You can browse slowly just as easily as quickly.

Comment: @JasonBassford So, _"browsing through the shelf"_ won't work right?

Comment: *Browsing through the shelf* is a perfectly fine phrase. But it doesn't mean that you were looking at the books at any particular speed. I could spend a minute browsing through books or hours.

Comment: @JasonBassford Oh, I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably say:
“I ‘**skimmed**’ through the bookshelf. ”

But with either option you choose, it would always help to add the adverb “quickly” for emphasis and brevity.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's right or wrong, but that's what I've been thinking.

Answer (score 1):

"Browsing through the shelf" or "browsing through the books on the shelf" could indeed be used for a quick look such as is shown in the animation. However, without context it would tend to imply a somewhat longer and more protracted examination.

"I scanned the bookshelf for X" or "I scanned the bookshelf for the title I wanted." (as suggested in the comment by Weather vane) comes closer, but even this tends to suggest a somewhat longer and more through examination of the books.

"I glanced at the shelf looking for X" or "I glanced through the books looking for X" suggests to me a very brief review of the books on the shelf.